# Bot that allows me to send a message to a specific Discord channel and will also be sent to a different channel?

Tags: discord, discord.js

How do I create a bot to when I send a message in a discord channel it also gets sent to different channel? Saves time rather than copying and pasting

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```js
message.channel.send(message)
message.client.channels.cache.get('<Put the channel ID here>').send(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want a bot that automatically sends a message that you send, to another channel?

```
bot.on("message", message => {
  if (message.author.id === "YOUR ID HERE") {
        message.client.channels.cache.get('<Put the channel ID here>').send(message.content)
  }
});
```